# Hibernate Annotation redundance

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm asking myself about some hibernate annotations when using at the same time.

For example:

```
@OneToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "taskID", nullable = false, unique = true)
private Task task;
```

Ok, it's a oneToOne not optionnal... So it's impossible to have null or duplicate, isn't it?
Do Hibernate do exactly the same thing accros all the differents DB?

In this case, what is preferable?... To be more precis, what do you prefer?
Saying nullable and unique or not?

I know it seems stupid but that's the kind of questions that I want to eradicate from my mind.

Comment: I think none of us can answer this since it depends on your business requirement

Comment: Really duplicate, my apologize.

Comment: "Do Hibernate do exactly the same thing accros all the differents DB?" How often do you plan to change the DB (vendor)?

Comment: @Bhesh Next week I do ^^ Every project I join begin with "We go from Maria to Postgres", or Oracle to Maria, or ... bothering me :s

Comment: That's sad :(. Not a good idea but nothing really that you can do. I feel sorry for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel it's generally best to avoid redundancy to keep things simple. If you are incredibly verbose all over the place it's hard to keep that consistency up. That's what defaults are for.

Hibernate follows the convention over configuration process fairly well:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration